# CSS - Grid with perfect squares

Tags: css

Need some help with the CSS for generating a grid of perfect squares. Div's look like this, but I'd like to have each of them look like a perfect square - not a rectangle. Setting width and height in css doesn't do it. :-\

`<div class="square" /> ... <div class="square" /> <div class="linebreak" />`

`<div class="square" /> ... <div class="square" /> <div class="linebreak" />`

Comment: display:block does not work btw...  http://jsfiddle.net/AYCkr/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to combine these style rules to get what you need. The float property ensures they stack in a horizontal row, the block rule allows you to set the height and width of the element and the overflow hidden rule stops it from expanding with the content.

```
.square {
    float: left;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: float left does it whew ! http://jsfiddle.net/AYCkr/1/

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to http://dinosaurswithlaserz.com/2011/07/18/fluid-squares-v2/ for pointing out it can be done with pure CSS and be fluid, like this:

```
.onesquare {

width: 30%;
margin: 0px 2% 0 0;
padding-bottom: 30%;
background-color: red;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats unusual

try something like this. It should work

```
.square {
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   display:block;
   overflow:hidden;
   float:left;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/EyXpC/

Comment: unfortunately, block breaks the horizontal rows... –

Comment: hahaha @ina, of course it does you have to float it. see the update

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:block` together with width and height attributes.

Comment: unfortunately, block breaks the horizontal rows...